# Key/Value custom webPart property - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, web-parts, key-value, custom-properties

Couldn't find any related resources
I want to add a custom property to my `visual webPart`, the normal way of adding properties not working with `type` of `Dictionary`

```
[Personalizable(), WebBrowsable(), WebDisplayName("News Sources"), WebDescription("description")]
public Dictionary<Guid,string> NewsSources { get; set; }
```

any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property of type `Dictionary` cannot be added to Custom WebPart.

If you want to have the dropdown list as the property, the backing store must be of type `enum`

See:

Creating a Web Part with Custom Properties
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Any alternatives for the dictionary incompatibility issue?

Comment: Yes, write a custom editor part http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228018.aspx

Comment: In that case, you cannot use visual webpart, you will have to write your own wrapper webpart, which will have your custom editor part